# Lift Kits or Air Suspension system for my 2015 Ram 4x4?

Tags: suspension, dodge, ram

I've got a 2015 Ram 1500 Eco diesel/6.5' bed, 4x4, with Pop Up camper on the bed. Weight of camper and gear is 1,000 lbs. Can you offer an opinion as to what would serve me best: lift kits or air suspension systems. I need to level the truck for heavy loads so I don't blind oncoming traffic at night. Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to level or actually lift the truck?

Comment: I need to level the truck so I don't blind oncoming drivers at night... it seems with the so-gentle coil springs even a few hundred pounds in the bed causes drivers coming at me to constantly flick their high beams.  Thanks Paulster2 for your inquiry.

Comment: Why don't you consider headlight adjustment to solve the issue with blinding oncoming traffic?

Comment: @oryades - The OP would have to adjust them every time they put a load on or took them off. Getting them set right can be a real pain, to say the least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need what is commonly referred to as a load leveler system. There are several systems out on the market, such as the [LoadLifter](https://www.airliftcompany.com/shop/88365/). There are several different types. The one I think would help you out the most is one (like mentioned) which will provide extra lift when there is a load on the vehicle.

Basically, there's a two way switch. When the suspension sags enough, the truck hits the switch (automatically) which activates the pump which inflates the springs, bringing the truck back up to its proper ride height. When the load is then relieved from the truck, the other side of the switch is hit, releasing the air, which brings it back down to the proper ride height. It's pretty slick and all automatic.

There are other kits which just provide extra support as the vehicle drops. These aren't as slick as the one I mentioned, but are a lot cheaper. You don't have to do anything with them, either, but the suspension is at the mercy of the helper spring.

The reason you don't want to use a lift kit in your situation is because it will only provide lift. It doesn't support anything. It doesn't provide any extra capacity. You'd still have the effect of the back end sagging. These kits are best used for aesthetics or when you need extra clearance for taller than stock tires and/or off-road use.

Comment: Yes, now I get it. You are right I don't just want to adjust the headlights, I need the load leveled. I came across the Firestone Ride-Rite air suspension system on line, late last night.  It looks like exactly what I need.  But I will look up the LoadLifter you mentioned, as well. Your input has been most valuable and I'm acquiring a vocabulary to more clearly express my needs and am grateful for suggestions put forth. Thanks.

Comment: @CalvinTitus - if this answers your question, please consider selecting the checkmark as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Some vehicles are factory fitted with auto-leveling headlights, but you might consider retrofitting your truck with a [kit](http://www.arz-tuning.de/shop/en/Hella-Ultrasonic-Automatic-Headlight-Leveling-System-Retrofit-Kit).  It seems a lot cheaper/easier than messing with the suspension if all you're trying to accomplish is headlight beam adjustment.